# readText function doesn't properly store standard input in a dynamic buffer

Tags: c, stdin

The function `readText` reads standard input and stores it (except new line characters, and '\0' which isn't expected in input) in a dynamic buffer. `readText` gets a pointer to the first allocation of the buffer. In main, the buffer is allocated in main:

```
int main() {
    char* buffer = calloc(STARTING_SIZE_OF_BUFFER, sizeof(char*));
    char** bufferPointer = malloc(sizeof(char**));
    *bufferPointer = buffer;
    readText(isBuffer, bufferPointer); /*read text and store memory state */
    printText(isBuffer, bufferPointer);
}
```

where `STARTING_SIZE_OF_BUFFER` is the size which you increase the buffer in each allocation. So at first the buffer has `STARTING_SIZE_OF_BUFFER` cells to be filled of char pointers, then if needed, twice the size and so on. The implementation of `readText` is:

```
int readText(void* structPointer)
{
    char* buffer = *(char**)(structPointer); /* structPointer is a pointer to a memory block */
    int noOfBlocks = 1; /* number of buffer allocations */
    int i, c;

    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            i--; /* no need to advance in buffer index, in next iteration i will be the same as before
                    the decrement */
            continue;
        }
        if (i == STARTING_SIZE_OF_BUFFER) /* need to allocate space */
        {
            buffer = realloc(buffer, STARTING_SIZE_OF_BUFFER * (noOfBlocks + 1)); /* times (noOfBlocks + 1) to increase the
                                                                    current buffer size by STARTING_SIZE_OF_BUFFER */
            if (buffer == NULL) /* couldn't a bigger memory block */
                return -1;
            noOfBlocks++;
            buffer[i] = c;
        }
        else
            buffer[i] = c;
    }
    buffer[i] = '\0'; /* indicate end of text */

    *(char**)(structPointer) = buffer;
    
    return 1;
}
```

There is also a function `printText` which prints the text in the given buffer. The implementation is as the following:

```
void printText(void* structPointer)
{
      char* buffer = *(char**)structPointer; /* structPointer is a pointer to a memory block */
      int i; /* buffer index */
      for (i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
      {
          if (i % CHARACTERS_PER_LINE == 0 && i != 0) /* if the program wrote */
              printf("%c", '\n');
          printf("%c", buffer[i]);
      }
}
```

where `CHARACTERS_PER_LINE` is a constant for indicating how many characters should be printed in each line.

**Note:** The formal parameters in both functions are declared as void pointers, because there is a need to handle the case where `structPointer` is a pointer to a linked-list, but that's irrelevant for now.

Sometimes the function will store the input as given, and sometimes it will store some non-ASCII / incorrect characters in the buffer. Different compilers also show me different results, for example, 2 running captures (the program should print the text as a block):
[image: MSVC]

[image: GCC]

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend that you debug those function using the return value instead of you just returning 1 try setting a standar error return value, and a error return value for each case, for example if the `c` variable is a non ASCII character `return -1`.
Also `realloc()` and `calloc()` always returns a `void` type pointer so you have to casted it, is very probably that your program is behaving wrong because of that

Answer (score 0):

```
char** bufferPointer = malloc(sizeof(char**));
```

isn't necessarily at all. malloc returns a pointer to the first char pointer in the allocated memory.